# Share DTO objects between WCF services

Tags: wcf, dto

I feel this is a stupid question even before asking, but my brain isn't working too well right now. I have two WCF services "CountryService" and "FloristService".

Now CountryService has the following method:

```
IList<CountryDTO> GetAllCountries();
```

Additionally, FloristService has a method:

```
bool AddFlorist(FloristDTO florist);
```

All good so far, but the problem is that the FloristDTO references a CountryDTO i.e.

```
    public  string Address1 { get; set; }
    public  string Address2 { get; set; }
    public  string Address3 { get; set; }
    public  string City { get; set; }
    public  string Postcode { get; set; }
    public  CountryDTO Country { get; set; }
    public  string Name { get; set; }
```

This is fine, but if I use the service proxy generating util with Visual Stuidos (i.e. Add Reference > Add Service Reference) then I get two versions of CountryDTO are created i.e.FloristService.CountryDTO and CountryService.CountryDTO.

Now I can think of a few ways to overcome this, but nonw of them seem right. I wondered what the "correct" approach to this would be, is there anything funky I can do with the proxy generation tool to make it share common DTOs?

Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reuse types in svcutil:
http://blogs.msdn.com/youssefm/archive/2009/10/09/reusing-types-in-referenced-assemblies-with-svcutil-s-r-switch.aspx

Comment: Second thoughts, this seems to assume that both the service layer and the consuming layer will have access to the same .dll with the DTO objects in. Now what If I dont have this, and I WANT the svutil generate the proxy classes. BUT I only want them generating once and shared across the services?

Comment: Then you generate the proxy classes once and reuse the generated proxy classes via svcutil /r for subsequent generation of your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Article ["How to reuse types across service endpoints"](http://www.drinkcoffeeandcode.com/blog/2011/03/01/how-to-reuse-types-across-service-endpoints/)  suggests on client side manually update Reference.svcmap to include multiple  and NamespaceMappings.

Alternatively svcutil does allow you to specify multiple endpoints at a single time and utilize /r(/reference)  and /n(/namespace) parameters.